# Changing functional component to class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to convert functional component to class component. Is it possible to use componentWillReceiveProps()?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = props => {
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [apps, setApps] = useState("Loading");
  console.log(props.id);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch(
        "https://m2dzass19b.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/vdrOptimize/21-09-2019"
      );
      res
        .json()
        .then(res => setApps(res))
        .catch(err => setErrors(err));
    }
    if (props.num === 2) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [props.num]);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{JSON.stringify(apps)}</span>
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
};

App.defaultProps = {
  num: 2
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Do not use [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops). Also; React is pushing to go more and more functional so why would you convert your already functional component to a class?

Comment: cause the environment im using uses class

Comment: They are compatible with each other, you don't have to use classes with classes. You can use both.

Comment: You can use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). Also your useEffect sets state when async value resolves but doesn't check if the component is still mounted.

Comment: Ah I was about to ask the same question as HMR :) Yes, you can use a mixture of class and function-based components, you don't need to stick to one or the other

Comment: You can use the `componentDidUpdate` to fetch data when the props.id changed, and use `componentDidMount` for the initial fetch (and show a nice loading state while data is not fetched yet). Move the fetching logic into a function and you can call it from both lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go super complicated, just stick to the basic lifecycle methods `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`:

```js
class AppClass extends Component {
  state = {
    hasError: false,
    apps: "Loading"
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.num === 2) {
      this.fetchData();
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.num === !this.props.num && props.num === 2) {
      this.fetchData();
    }
  }

  async fetchData = () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://m2dzass19b.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/vdrOptimize/21-09-2019"
    );
    res
      .json()
      .then(res => setState({ apps: res }))
      .catch(err => setState({ hasError: err }));
  };

  render() {
    const { apps } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <span>{JSON.stringify(apps)}</span>
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is how you can use componentWillReceiveProps

```
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
async function fetchData() {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://m2dzass19b.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/vdrOptimize/21-09-2019"
  );
  res
    .json()
    .then(res => this.setState({ apps: res }))
    .catch(err => this.setState({ hasError: err }));
}
if (nextProps.id === 2) {
  fetchData.call(this);
}
```

}

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-hawking-wk91d)

Note: I am using id instead of num prop

Hope it helps

Comment: You should not use [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) the documentation has a bunch of alternatives so why keep using it?

Comment: i know its deprecated that's why i used UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps,